# MYSQL error code 1452... I can not seem to solve the issue

Tags: mysql

[Picture#1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWmkB.png)

[Picture #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh2FG.png)

I have been playing around for hours and I can not seem to fix the issue. I've tried countless methods, but none seem to work. I am trying to import a csv file.

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) **as you were asked to do when you registered**
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Looks like you are trying to create a Product before you have created the respective Vendor

Comment: You need to create all vendors before you try to import products. FKs do not push values into parent tables you need to do so.